# MongoDB / Mongoose - Text search inside array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need to perform a text search inside array elements. Is it possible?

Using Mongoose in Node.js and my userSchema looks like:

```
{
 _id: "123456",
 name: "Lucas"
 items: [
  { title: "Shoes", description: "Very nice shoes"}, 
  { title: "Pants", description: "Great pants!"}
 ]
}
```

I tried to add the indexes like this:

```
userSchema.index({ "items.title": "text", "items.description": "text" });
```

But the following query returns nothing:

```
User.find({  $text: { $search: "Shoes" }});
```

Comment: It work fine when tried from `mongo` shell. The text search on "Shoes" will match both  the `title` and `description` fields, where the text values "Shoes" and "... nice shoes" are the matches.

Comment: Can you return any records? e.g. try User.find()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mongoose isn't an index management solution. So don't rely on mongoose to create indexes. They even state this on their docs at [faq](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html).

> In a production environment, you should create your indexes using the
>   MongoDB shell rather than relying on mongoose to do it for you.

So all you need to do is creating the text index at mongodb shell.
If the collection name is different from `users` you need to change also below.

```js
db.users.createIndex(
    {
        "items.title": "text",
        "items.description": "text",
    }
)
```

Comment: That's it! Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked with @typegoose index decorator.

```
@index({
    _id: "text",
    name: "text",
    items: "text",
    "items.title": "text",
    "items.description": "text",
})
export class User {
    @prop({ required: true }) public name: string;
    @prop({ required: true }) public items: Array<ItemInterface>;
}
```